# How to get the all directory list which directory have common directory using batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to get the folder directory which have common directory using batch

I have tried but getting all directory list

```
for /r /d %%s in (\myfolder\*) do (
    @echo %%~fs
 )
```

Folder directory :

```
- myfolder
  - temp1
    - common_directory
  - temp2
    - common_directory
  - temp 3
   - folder_3
```

I want below directory only :

```
- myfolder/temp1/common_directory
- myfolder/temp2/common_directory
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
forfiles /S /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE echo @path" | findstr /I "common_directory"
```

Let me explain:

- `forfiles /S` : go into subdirectories
- `forfiles /C` : launch a script inside your forfiles session
  more can be found using `forfiles /?`
- `| findstr /I "common_directory` : `/I` makes it case insensitive

Have fun!

P.s. According to [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo), you can avoid using `Findstr` using the following command:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /S /P "myfolder" /M "common_directory" /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C \"If @IsDir == TRUE If /I @File == \"common_directory\" Echo @Path\"" 2>NUL
```

Comment: I would advise the OP not to do it like this. If using `forfiles.exe` for the task, there should be no need to use also `findstr.exe`.

Comment: @Compo: you're right: there should be a way to say `if @isdir==TRUE AND @file=="common_directory"` but the problem is: I don't know how to write an AND-clause in command prompt and I also don't know how to deal with the double quotes. Do you have an idea? In case yes, feel free to update my answer.

Comment: Why can you not use a second `IF` instead of the `AND`? Can you not create a temporary file structure, and try it?

Comment: This answer is not useful for me. I want to crate batch file which give above output

Comment: @ranimane: ... and what's wrong with the output from my proposal?

Comment: TBF, @ranimane, you have not submitted anything which defines the exact output you require! Please edit your question to define the exact required output.

Comment: @Dominique, as an extension of my suggested change, ```%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /S /P "myfolder" /M "common_directory" /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C \"If @IsDir == TRUE If /I @File == \"common_directory\" Echo @Path\"" 2>NUL```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
:: remove variables starting ?
FOR  /F "delims==" %%b In ('set ? 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%b="

for /r "%sourcedir%" /d %%e in (*) do (
IF "!?%%~nxe!"=="" (
  SET "?%%~nxe=%%e"
 ) ELSE (
 ECHO !?%%~nxe!
 ECHO %%e
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

Simply set a variable `?leafname` to the directoryname found if it's not already set, or `echo` the value stored and the newly-found name if it has been set by encountering the same leafname previously.

I used `?` before the leafname as `?` can't appear in a leafname.